# Ubuntu PHP href link not working

Tags: php, linux

I have PHP Version 7.0.8-0ubuntu0.16.04.3 running on a server at home.

I am trying to link to a file using;

```
<?php echo "Software Version - " . $thisVersion. "<a href=\"includes/getUpdate.php\">" . $updateAvalable . "</a>"; ?>
```

The text in the $updateAvailable string gets displayed as a link but does nothing when clicked on.

What is perplexing is that this same piece of code works fine on a remote server I have access to.
I suspect this maybe due to some setting on my home server but I am at a loss with this now.

Cheers in advance for any help.

Here most off the code;

```
$serverVersion = "ftp://ServerLogonDetails/someText.txt";
$handle = fopen($serverVersion, "r");
$latestVersion = fgets($handle);
fclose;

// Get the software version 
if (($_SESSION[Page] == "Config")||($_SESSION[Page] == "backUpRec")){
    $localVersion = "daemon_ver.txt";
    $handle = fopen($localVersion, "r") or die($openLocalFile = FALSE);
    $currentVersion = fgets($handle);
    fclose;
}
else if (($_SESSION[Page] == "System")||($_SESSION[Page] == "Users")){
    // Get the software version on the VS-One unit
    $localVersion = "../daemon_ver.txt";
    $handle = fopen($localVersion, "r") or die($openLocalFile = TRUE);
    $currentVersion = fgets($handle);
    fclose;
}

if ($latestVersion <= $currentVersion) {
    $updateAvalable = "";
}
else if ($latestVersion > $currentVersion){
    $updateAvalable = " Update Available";
}

?>

</head>
<body>

<table id="footersmall" width="940" border="0" cellspacing="10" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
        <td class="version"><?php echo "Software Version - ".$thisVersion."<a href=\"includes/getUpdate.php\">".$updateAvalable . "</a>"; ?></td>
    </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Post the HTML output.  You're just using PHP to output HTML.  Once the HTML is output, it is up to your browser to render it.

Comment: Have your rewrited URL ? In this case add "/" to "/includes/getUpdate.php". Try to not escape string use simple quote when you have double quotes in a string

Comment: 1. does remote server has a .htaccess file in the project root, if so, please post contents (P.S.) .htaccess is hidden so use ls -all to list files. when you create a link without starting slash it creates a link like {current_url}href_content. When you use a "/" at the start of you href, it builds url like {base_url}{/href_url}.

Comment: 1- What should happen when you click on the link? 2- if you put this file `includes/getUpdate.php` directly in your browser address bar(on your local machine) what will happen?

Answer (score 0):

try slash at beginning
`"<a href=\"/includes/getUpdate.php\">"`

...if "includes" is at the web root, of cause...

Comment: I am not sure that is the problem. The link does work if I use this; "<a href=\"#\"> or "<a href='#'>

Comment: anyway, lets see the generated HTMLs from both cases (just copy-paste exact html output from case it works and case it doesnt work)